# Viewing the text inside Pyspark object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am able to load an log file using the following command:

```
logFile = sc.textFile("/resources/jupyterlab/labs/BD0211EN/LabData/notebook.log")
```

But when I try to see the `log` file contents, I am not able to do. I checked `dir(logFile)`, but I am not able to see the content inside. Now when I run the code in the Jupyter cell, I get the following:

```
/resources/jupyterlab/labs/BD0211EN/LabData/notebook.log MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
```

Is it possible to see the contents of the log file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is the following:

```
logFile.collect()
```

This will show you the content's that are split line wise.